# Distinction between "Derivative is defined/undefined" and "Derivative exists/does-not-exist"

Tags: calculus, limits, logic

I would like to better understand the distinction between the terms *undefined*, *defined*, *exists*, and *does not exist*. I have read this ([Difference between "undefined" and "does not exist"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296149/difference-between-undefined-and-does-not-exist)) post, but I still fail to grasp the distinctions completely.

The particular examples I have been working with come from the following two theorems:

\begin{align}
&(1) \quad\text{if } f^{(n)}(c) \text{ DNE, then for any } x \gt n \text{ , }\color{red}{f^{(x)}(c) \text{ is undefined}}\\
&(2) \quad \text{ if }f^{(n)}(c) \text{ exists, then for any } x \text{ such that } 0 \lt x \leq n  \text{ , }f^{(n-x)}(c) \text{ exists}
\end{align}

Using the above two theorems to provide context, I want to confirm whether or not the following statement is mathematically valid: If a derivative at a point *exists*, then the derivative at the point is *defined*. This seems to make sense from an English interpretation, however, I find that something is fishy about whether or not this implication is actually valid in math's logical framework.

Is the notion of "defined" a legitimate feature of an object? i.e. is it legal to make a proposition of the form $\varphi(\cdot):= \cdot\text{ is a defined object}$.

For example, $\varphi(\ln(0))$ would be false, whereas $\varphi(\ln(2))$ would be true. If this is legitimate, then it feels appropriate to let the negation of *defined* be *undefined* (...we already know that the negation of *exists* is *does not exist*). Further, if this is the case, then we can certainly assert that the contrapositive of "If a derivative at a point *exists*, then the derivative at the point is *defined*" is a valid construct: "If a derivative at a point is undefined, then the derivative at the point does not exist."

Accordingly, the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ consequent of the 1st theorem can be changed to: $f^{(x)}(c) \text{ DNE}$.

Comment: Quick example regarding the terminology: the derivative of $\sqrt[3]{x}$ is **undefined** at $x=0$, while the derivative of $|x|$ **does not exist** at $x=0$; the derivative of $x$ **exists** and is **defined** at $x=0$.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 I'm still quite the novice, but I do not believe that is true regarding the cube root claim. I provided an answer here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1167558/cube-root-function-not-differentiable/4236427#4236427), which shows that the derivative approaches infinity. This would therefore be an instance of the derivative not existing (which is confirmed from the answer to this post here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4110358/why-do-we-call-a-limit-that-evaluates-to-displaystyle-pm-infty-a-particular-i)

Comment: Have a look at the [accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1167572/818304) on the same post. The derivative clearly exists, but is not defined. We say the derivative exists and the derivative from the left and right are equal, here they both are $\infty$. But that is matter of definitions; if you include the restriction of derivative being real, then the answer is different.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 thank you for the response - that is good to know...and now I am even more confused hah.

Comment: Some things in mathematics don't have a full consensus on one definition. Okay, so what definition do **you** use for defining whether the derivative exists or not? If that's your question, then I recommend using whatever definition your teacher/book prefers.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 Not sure if this is unreasonably pedantic, but to refer back to your "accepted answer" hyper link, I would think that the author of the post made a slight mistake. His formula for the derivative is only valid for $x \neq 0$. Said differently, it seems more appropriate to break down $f'$ into two functions...one which is restricted to the domain of $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ and one which is restricted to $\{0\}$. In this sense, I think the author should have written $f' \upharpoonright \mathbb R \setminus \{0\} = nx^{n-1}$, in which case, of course it is undefined at $x=0$.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 however, this does not mean that $f'$ is undefined at $x=0$. I think, if anything, it is then clear that $f' \upharpoonright \{0\} = \infty$, in which case, referencing my previous comments, $f'(0)$ does not exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129386/discussion-between-ultralegend5385-and-s-cramer).

Comment: To say that $\dfrac 0 0$ is *undefined* means simply that there is **no** number $r$ that is the result of the operation of dividing $0$ with $0$